# How to embed Ruffle flash player emulator into HTML file?

Tags: flash, emulation, ruffle

I need help on implementing a swf into my HTML site with ruffle (https://ruffle.rs/), I added "AddType application/wasm .wasm" into httpd.conf in  in apache, and this is my code but it does not display on my localhost server :

```
<html><head><script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
    window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
        const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
        const player = ruffle.createPlayer();
        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.appendChild(player);
        player.load("mig29.swf");
    });
</script>
<script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>

</body>
</html
```

I also tried this code, also no luck:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WORKAROUND</title>

    <script>
        window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
        window.RufflePlayer.config = {
            "public_path": "ruffle/",
            "polyfills": ["static-content", "plugin-detect", "dynamic-content"]
        };
    </script>
    <script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>

    <!-- Start workaround -->
    <script>
        const swfobject = {};
    </script>
    <script>
        Object.defineProperty(swfobject, "embedSWF", {
            value: function() {
                var ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
                var player = ruffle.create_player();
                var container = document.getElementById(arguments[1]);
                container.innerHTML = "";
                container.style.width = arguments[2] + "px";
                container.style.height = arguments[3] + "px";
                player.style.width = container.style.width;
                player.style.height = container.style.height;
                container.appendChild(player);
                player.stream_swf_url(arguments[0]);
            },
            writable: false,
            configurable: false
        });
    </script>
    <!-- End workaround - This code also works if placed before <swfobject.js> -->

    <script src="swfobject.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="file_div">Flash Player not detected!</div>
<script>
    swfobject.embedSWF("mig29.swf", "file_div", "550", "400", "8");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I asked their discord but no answer so far. If anyone is more familiar with ruffle please assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have recently discovered how to get this working. Calling .play on the player returned by `ruffle.createPlayer()` takes an object or at least expects one.  Doing `player.load({ url: '/path/to/swf.swf' })` will work

```
swfobject.embedSWF = function(url, cont, width, height){
    var ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest(),
        player = Object.assign(document.getElementById(cont).appendChild(ruffle.createPlayer()), {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            style: 'width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px',
        });
    
    player.load({ url: url });
}
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf8'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='ruffle'></div>
        <script src='https://e9x.github.io/ruffle-example/ruffle.js'></script>
        <script>
var swfobject = {};

swfobject.embedSWF = function(url, cont, width, height){
    var ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest(),
        player = Object.assign(document.getElementById(cont).appendChild(ruffle.createPlayer()), {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            style: 'width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px',
        });
    
    player.load({ url: url });
}

swfobject.embedSWF('https://e9x.github.io/ruffle-example/1on1soccer_24.swf', 'ruffle', 500, 500);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Replace github.io links with your own)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, could you please put the complete code with html and body, I still cannot get this to work

Comment: Sorry, I made a small typo. I will edit the post to include the full code

Comment: Hi, many thanks, do you perhaps know if something else need to be configured in apache besides the "AddType application/wasm .wasm" ?  With your link https://e9x.github.io/ruffle/ruffle.js it works for me now, but if I test it locally (just  ruffle/ruffle.js) then nothing loads.

Comment: I believe CORS may be the issue?

Comment: i modified your first line to this, that made ruffle boot my game: 

`var swfobject = {ua: {pv: {}}, hasFlashPlayerVersion() { return true }};`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created the `<div>` for the player.

All this following code between `<body>` and `</body>` :

```
<div id="container"> </div>

<script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
        window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
            const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
            const player = ruffle.createPlayer();
            const container = document.getElementById("container"); 
            container.appendChild(player);
            player.load({
                url: "mig29.swf", 
                backgroundColor: "#000", 
             });
            player.style.width = "450px"; 
            player.style.height = "450px";
        });
    </script>
```

Remember to add this line on your `.htaccess` and upload it:

`AddType application/wasm .wasm wasm`

and, also, remember to upload the whole carpet of ruffle selfhosted (6 files) to the root.